# Magento 2 : If the not logged user click to checkout, then popup will show for login or sign-up

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

### Checkout button:

### (Minicart)

[image]

### (Shopping cart)

[image]

### Popup will show:

[image]

### I'm new in Magento 2, please help me

Comment: Do you want to disable checkout for guests??

Comment: If the not logged user click the button "Proceed to Checkout" the popup will show

Answer (score 1):

Magento By default provides this functionality,

**How to Disable checkout for Guest User:**

1. On the Admin sidebar, go to **Stores > Settings > Configuration**.
2. On the left panel, **expand Sales** and **choose Checkout**.
3. Expand the Checkout Options section.
4. If the setting is for a specific store view, choose the store view where the configuration applies. When prompted, click OK to continue.
   [image: Disable guest checkout]
5. Set **Allow Guest Checkout** to **No**.

   If necessary, clear the Use system value checkbox to enable changes to this setting.
6. Click Save Config.

*Hope it helps you.*

Answer (score 0):

Magento default already supports disabling Guest (not logged in user) checkout but it is disabled by default. So, you don't need to re-implement that feature, just change the config.

To disable Guest checkout, go to the admin sidebar > Stores > Configuration > `Sales` section > `Checkout` tab > `Checkout Options`. Set the config `Allow Guest Checkout` to **No**, then save the config and clear the cache.